JWT::decode Expected type 'stdClass|null'. Found 'string'
Tengo la siguiente funcion para comprobar si un usuario esta logeado en PHP, el problema esta en que al usar JWT::decode, me da el error nombrado cuando le paso el JWT_ALG. Estoy usando la libreria firebase.
api.php:
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method, X-Auth-Token");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PATCH, DELETE');
header("Allow: GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE");
use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'OPTIONS') {
    return 0;
}

require_once(__DIR__.'/../config/config.php');
require_once(__DIR__.'/../config/generals.php');
require_once(__DIR__.'/../config/jwt.php');

function requireLogin(){
    $authHeader = getallheaders();
    try{
        list($jwt) = @sscanf($authHeader['Authorization'], 'Bearer %s');
        $datos = JWT::decode($jwt, JWT_KEY, JWT_ALG);
        $db = conectarBD();
        $jwtSql = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $jwt);
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $jwtSql);
        if (!$result){
            outputError(500);
        } else if(mysqli_num_rows($result) != 1){
            outputError(403);
        }
        mysqli_close($db);
    }catch(Exception $e){
        outputError(401);
    }
}

jwt.php:
<?

define ('JWT_ALG', 'HS512'); // JWT_ALG de codificación/firma
define ('JWT_KEY', '77cf.762d2664357c9e35fa6AÑ-cf548a8/f61b5c7931504f16f7d$2c3f84*0b'); 
define ('JWT_EXP', 3600); // Duración en segundos de la validez del token

Me llama la atencion, que al usar el JWT::encode de la misma manera, no da ningun error. Que deberia cambiar?

Proba así: JWT::decode($jwt, new Key(JWT_KEY, JWT_ALG)). Más info. PD: Recordá que si logras resolverlo, podes responder a tu propia pregunta y así ayudar a otros.

Lo solucione de la siguiente manera, agregue use Firebase\JWT\Key; y el codigo quedo:
function requireLogin(){
    $authHeader = getallheaders();
    try{
        list($jwt) = @sscanf($authHeader['Authorization'], 'Bearer %s');
        $datos = JWT::decode($jwt, new Key(JWT_KEY, JWT_ALG));
        $db = conectarBD();
        $jwtSql = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $jwt);
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $jwtSql);
        if (!$result){
            outputError(500);
        } else if(mysqli_num_rows($result) != 1){
            outputError(403);
        }
        mysqli_close($db);
    }catch(Exception $e){
        outputError(401);
    }
}


Felicitaciones! En un par de dias vas a poder marcarla como "aceptada".
